# Pip is looking for python in wrong directory

Tags: python, directory, python-3.9

Pip is looking for python in a directory that no longer exists. I downgraded from python 3.10 to python 3.9 using Microsoft app store after my original python 3.10 had an error running pip install pyqt5-tools. I have tried adding my new python to PATH but it doesn't work. I am trying to convert a UI file to a PY file using pyuic5.

I tried

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python --version
```

It gave

```
No Python at '"C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe'
```

I also tried

```
where python
```

and it gave

```
C:\Users\Ponsar Kumzhi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
```

This suggests that Windows knows where the correct installation of python is located.
I have tried adding this new directory to path and it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You probably missed out something or there is some issues with your computer. To update the PATH environment variable is probably the only solution to fix this issue.

1. Search for "Environment Variables" in the search bar.
2. Click on "Edit the system environment variables".
3. In the System Properties window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
   Scroll down to the "Path" variable in the "System Variables" section and select it.
4. Click on the "Edit" button and "New" button and add the path to the Python 3.9 installation directory. For your case, it is: `C:\Users\Ponsar Kumzhi\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Scripts\python.exe`.
   Click on "OK" lastly.

After you finished the above mentioned steps, press `Windows + R` and type `cmd`, then press enter. Try typing "py --version" and it should print "Python [version]". You should then be able to use pip to install packages and use pyuic5 command.